# Only use 2 dictionaries in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want to have a German and an English dictionary in Firefox. However, at the moment I have 11; 6 different German versions and 5 different English versions. Thats how it looks in my browser if I select a language:

[image]

I only want to use German language from Germany (Deutschland) and English language from USA (Vereinigt Staaten von Amerika). How can I remove the other ones?

Under `Add-Ons->Dictionaries` I have exactly the two dictionaries that I want:

[image]

And I have disabled the language packs (although I have no idea what they are used for):

[image]

However I still can choose between 11 languages on spell checking - why?

Edit:

This is shown under `Configuration->General->Language->Choose...`

[image]

This is shown under `Systemsettings->Languages`

[image]

Comment: What is your OS, and version of FF? There is this - [Use the Firefox interface in other languages with language packs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-interface-other-languages-language-pack). Is a localized version of FF installed? And what languages are displayed under Options -->General-->Language (Choose)?

Comment: Having said that, don't presume that the 11 languages come from FF. They may be system installed languages.

Comment: @user3169 I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I checked you link but it coulnd't help be, because `intl.locale.matchOS` was already set to false. I don't know what you mean with localized version of FF, I do not remember if I have installed anything except language packs and dictionaries. I made a screen shot showing you the displayed default browser languages. I also made a screen shot showing the system installed langauges (Systemsettings->Languages). I have no idea where the 11 languages come from.-

Comment: When I added the German dictionary (top item of the three on the dictionary download page), I only see one German in the context menu. Since you can see them, maybe remove the German dictionary and re-install. Language Packs are a separate matter. They are used to provide the correct fonts for web page display.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks for all your help so far! I am Using FF 56.0 64 bit. If I go to Add Ons it still looks like the screen shot, are you sure they have changed the menu? I removed the German dictionary and restarted my laptop, but it still shows 6 different German dictionaries, although the German dictionary is not shown under `Add-ons->Dictonary`

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the menus, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all unneeded dictionaries at

```
/usr/share/hunspell/
```

I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5136/how-to-remove-all-that-country-specific-dictionaries-like-en-au-en-ca-de-ch